# How to set different font sizes for different devices using Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, fonts, font-size, xcode-storyboard

I want to set different font sizes for iPhone 5, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone X using Xcode Storyboard.

Can anyone offer any advice?

[image: Example is shown in the image where i was stuck.]

Comment: you can set global font in app delegate...

Comment: see this it helps you : https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195

Comment: there is also one more tick i use for same is Use "AutoShrink" and select last one "Minimum Font Size" use value 0.5 and now assign your max size of font to this label and you done ;)

Comment: Check below link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496831/5857254 Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [Size-Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html) and add size variation for fonts from `Attribute Inspector` of Label property.

Here are different possible variations, you can set with Size class:

[image]

[image]

Try this:

[image]

[image]

Here is (result) preview of font-size variation, in iPhone and iPad

[image]

## Update

The result you are expecting, may not be possible using IB (Storyboard) but you can try it with following programmatic solution:

```
extension UIDevice {
    
    
    enum DeviceType: String {
        case iPhone4_4S = "iPhone 4 or iPhone 4S"
        case iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE = "iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 5c or iPhone SE"
        case iPhones_6_6s_7_8 = "iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 7 or iPhone 8"
        case iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus = "iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus or iPhone 8 Plus"
        case iPhoneX = "iPhone X"
        case unknown = "iPadOrUnknown"
    }
    
    var deviceType: DeviceType {
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            return .iPhone4_4S
        case 1136:
            return .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE
        case 1334:
            return .iPhones_6_6s_7_8
        case 1920, 2208:
            return .iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus
        case 2436:
            return .iPhoneX
        default:
            return .unknown
        }
    }
}


// Get device type (with help of above extension) and assign font size accordingly.
let label = UILabel()

let deviceType = UIDevice.current.deviceType

switch deviceType {
    
case .iPhone4_4S:
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    
case .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE:
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    
case .iPhones_6_6s_7_8:
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    
case .iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus:
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    
case .iPhoneX:
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    
default:
    print("iPad or Unkown device")
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

}
```

Comment: you can't have adifferent variation in font not layout for iPhone 6 ,7 and X ,,, R,R for ipad

Comment: @Sh_Khan - You are welcomed to share your inputs and improve quality of this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks... @Krunal

Comment: Note, that you can add font variations ONLY if you have enabled "Use Trait Variation" for your storyboard. Spent hours finding that...

Answer (score 3):

Note: This is not a straightforward answer. However, this can be achieved based on the constraints.

If you are using autolayout, you can have the font scale automatically through storyboards. In the `Attributes` inspector for `UILabel`, there is an `Autoshrink` section where you can set the `Minimum Font Size` or `Minimum Font Scale`. So, as your label resizes itself through constraints, it will also scale down your fonts to fit.[image]

Comment: how do you set the constraint? because it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

You can't accomplish this in IB , you can detect the current device at runtime with it's size and set the font accordingly , if all elements have same font you can use .appearnce to set a global font

There is no font variation for IPhone 6,7,X , it has to be in code not IB