# How to iOS item and font sizes scaling as screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I want to make item and font sizes looking same as screen sizes. I used to use item ratio for scaling to handle different iOS screen but there was problem with item's size which is hugely increasing bigger iOS screen.Also, I have created FontHelper which is adjust  font size as screen size.For example,If I have defined font size as 17 in iPhone SE, size will be 19 in iPhone 8 , 21 in iPhone 8 Plus etc. As I know that if I define item size height a specific number, it will be adjusted as device screen. The same way is for label's font size, if I define font size as specific number, it will be adjusted as device screen because it is defined by points, but I have created XIB file and put views with different height and label with different font size to check whether they will be adjusted. As you can see, they are looking completely same.

Are they adjusted or am I totally misunderstanding about Point in iOS Development? Is there any suggestion to handle size and font for different iOS devices?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to handle different font size for different iPhone models. You have to create custom class for that. Check the code below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// for label
class ClassLabelSizeClass: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        switch UIDevice().type {
        case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S, .iPhone5C:
            self.font = self.font.withSize(?*self.font.pointSize)
        case .iPhone6, .iPhone6S, .iPhone7, .iPhone8:
            self.font = self.font.withSize(?*self.font.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhone6plus, .iPhone6Splus, .iPhone7plus, .iPhone8plus:
            self.font = self.font.withSize(?*self.font.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhoneX, .iPhoneXR, .iPhoneXS, .iPhoneXSMax, .iPhone11, .iPhone11Pro, .iPhone11ProMax:
           self.font = self.font.withSize(?*self.font.pointSize + 3)
        default:
           self.font = self.font.withSize(?*self.font.pointSize + 4)
        }
    }
}

//for textfield
class ClassTextFieldSizeClass: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        switch UIDevice().type {
        case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S, .iPhone5C:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize)
        case .iPhone6, .iPhone6S, .iPhone7, .iPhone8:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhone6plus, .iPhone6Splus, .iPhone7plus, .iPhone8plus:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhoneX, .iPhoneXR, .iPhoneXS, .iPhoneXSMax, .iPhone11, .iPhone11Pro, .iPhone11ProMax:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 3)
        default:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 4)
        }
    }
}  

//for button
class ClassButtonSizeClass: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        switch UIDevice().type {
        case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S, .iPhone5C:
            self.titleLabel?.font = self.titleLabel?.font.withSize(?*self.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)
        case .iPhone6, .iPhone6S, .iPhone7, .iPhone8:
            self.titleLabel?.font = self.titleLabel?.font.withSize(?*self.titleLabel?.font.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhone6plus, .iPhone6Splus, .iPhone7plus, .iPhone8plus:
            self.titleLabel?.font = self.titleLabel?.font.withSize(?*self.titleLabel?.font.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhoneX, .iPhoneXR, .iPhoneXS, .iPhoneXSMax, .iPhone11, .iPhone11Pro, .iPhone11ProMax:
            self.titleLabel?.font = self.titleLabel?.font.withSize(?*self.titleLabel?.font.pointSize + 3)
        default:
            self.titleLabel?.font = self.titleLabel?.font.withSize(?*self.titleLabel?.font.pointSize + 4)
        }
    }
}

// for textView
class ClassTextViewSizeClass: UITextView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        switch UIDevice().type {
        case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S, .iPhone5C:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize)
        case .iPhone6, .iPhone6S, .iPhone7, .iPhone8:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhone6plus, .iPhone6Splus, .iPhone7plus, .iPhone8plus:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 2)
        case .iPhoneX, .iPhoneXR, .iPhoneXS, .iPhoneXSMax, .iPhone11, .iPhone11Pro, .iPhone11ProMax:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 3)
        default:
            self.font = self.font?.withSize(?*self.font?.pointSize + 4)
        }
    }
}

//for custom value returning
class ClassUIDeviceTypeReturn {

     static let shared = ClassUIDeviceTypeReturn()

     func returnFloatValue(iPhone5: CGFloat, iPhone6: CGFloat, iPhone6Plus: CGFloat, iPhoneX: CGFloat, iPadDefault: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        switch UIDevice().type {
        case .iPhoneSE, .iPhone5, .iPhone5S, .iPhone5C:
            return iPhone5
         case .iPhone6, .iPhone6S, .iPhone7, .iPhone8:
            return iPhone6
         case .iPhone6plus, .iPhone6Splus, .iPhone7plus, .iPhone8plus:
            return iPhone6Plus
         case .iPhoneX, .iPhoneXR, .iPhoneXS, .iPhoneXSMax, .iPhone11, .iPhone11Pro, .iPhone11ProMax:
            return iPhoneX
         default:
            return iPadDefault
         }
     }
}

public enum EnumModel: String {
case simulator     = "simulator/sandbox",
//iPod
iPod1              = "iPod 1",
iPod2              = "iPod 2",
iPod3              = "iPod 3",
iPod4              = "iPod 4",
iPod5              = "iPod 5",
//iPad
iPad2              = "iPad 2",
iPad3              = "iPad 3",
iPad4              = "iPad 4",
iPadAir            = "iPad Air ",
iPadAir2           = "iPad Air 2",
iPad5              = "iPad 5", //aka iPad 2017
iPad6              = "iPad 6", //aka iPad 2018
//iPad mini
iPadMini           = "iPad Mini",
iPadMini2          = "iPad Mini 2",
iPadMini3          = "iPad Mini 3",
iPadMini4          = "iPad Mini 4",
//iPad pro
iPadPro9_7         = "iPad Pro 9.7\"",
iPadPro10_5        = "iPad Pro 10.5\"",
iPadPro12_9        = "iPad Pro 12.9\"",
iPadPro2_12_9      = "iPad Pro 2 12.9\"",
//iPhone
iPhone4            = "iPhone 4",
iPhone4S           = "iPhone 4S",
iPhone5            = "iPhone 5",
iPhone5S           = "iPhone 5S",
iPhone5C           = "iPhone 5C",
iPhone6            = "iPhone 6",
iPhone6plus        = "iPhone 6 Plus",
iPhone6S           = "iPhone 6S",
iPhone6Splus       = "iPhone 6S Plus",
iPhoneSE           = "iPhone SE",
iPhone7            = "iPhone 7",
iPhone7plus        = "iPhone 7 Plus",
iPhone8            = "iPhone 8",
iPhone8plus        = "iPhone 8 Plus",
iPhoneX            = "iPhone X",
iPhoneXS           = "iPhone XS",
iPhoneXSMax        = "iPhone XS Max",
iPhoneXR           = "iPhone XR",
iPhone11           = "iPhone 11",
iPhone11Pro        = "iPhone 11 Pro",
iPhone11ProMax     = "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
//Apple TV
AppleTV            = "Apple TV",
AppleTV_4K         = "Apple TV 4K",
unrecognized       = "?unrecognized?"
}

// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
// MARK: UIDevice extensions
// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#

public extension UIDevice {
public var type: EnumModel {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
            ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)

        }
    }
    var modelMap : [ String: EnumModel ] = [
        "i386": .simulator,
        "x86_64": .simulator,
        //iPod
        "iPod1,1": .iPod1,
        "iPod2,1": .iPod2,
        "iPod3,1": .iPod3,
        "iPod4,1": .iPod4,
        "iPod5,1": .iPod5,
        //iPad
        "iPad2,1": .iPad2,
        "iPad2,2": .iPad2,
        "iPad2,3": .iPad2,
        "iPad2,4": .iPad2,
        "iPad3,1": .iPad3,
        "iPad3,2": .iPad3,
        "iPad3,3": .iPad3,
        "iPad3,4": .iPad4,
        "iPad3,5": .iPad4,
        "iPad3,6": .iPad4,
        "iPad4,1": .iPadAir,
        "iPad4,2": .iPadAir,
        "iPad4,3": .iPadAir,
        "iPad5,3": .iPadAir2,
        "iPad5,4": .iPadAir2,
        "iPad6,11": .iPad5, //aka iPad 2017
        "iPad6,12": .iPad5,
        "iPad7,5": .iPad6, //aka iPad 2018
        "iPad7,6": .iPad6,
        //iPad mini
        "iPad2,5": .iPadMini,
        "iPad2,6": .iPadMini,
        "iPad2,7": .iPadMini,
        "iPad4,4": .iPadMini2,
        "iPad4,5": .iPadMini2,
        "iPad4,6": .iPadMini2,
        "iPad4,7": .iPadMini3,
        "iPad4,8": .iPadMini3,
        "iPad4,9": .iPadMini3,
        "iPad5,1": .iPadMini4,
        "iPad5,2": .iPadMini4,
        //iPad pro
        "iPad6,3": .iPadPro9_7,
        "iPad6,4": .iPadPro9_7,
        "iPad7,3": .iPadPro10_5,
        "iPad7,4": .iPadPro10_5,
        "iPad6,7": .iPadPro12_9,
        "iPad6,8": .iPadPro12_9,
        "iPad7,1": .iPadPro2_12_9,
        "iPad7,2": .iPadPro2_12_9,
        //iPhone
        "iPhone3,1": .iPhone4,
        "iPhone3,2": .iPhone4,
        "iPhone3,3": .iPhone4,
        "iPhone4,1": .iPhone4S,
        "iPhone5,1": .iPhone5,
        "iPhone5,2": .iPhone5,
        "iPhone5,3": .iPhone5C,
        "iPhone5,4": .iPhone5C,
        "iPhone6,1": .iPhone5S,
        "iPhone6,2": .iPhone5S,
        "iPhone7,1": .iPhone6plus,
        "iPhone7,2": .iPhone6,
        "iPhone8,1": .iPhone6S,
        "iPhone8,2": .iPhone6Splus,
        "iPhone8,4": .iPhoneSE,
        "iPhone9,1": .iPhone7,
        "iPhone9,3": .iPhone7,
        "iPhone9,2": .iPhone7plus,
        "iPhone9,4": .iPhone7plus,
        "iPhone10,1": .iPhone8,
        "iPhone10,4": .iPhone8,
        "iPhone10,2": .iPhone8plus,
        "iPhone10,5": .iPhone8plus,
        "iPhone10,3": .iPhoneX,
        "iPhone10,6": .iPhoneX,
        "iPhone11,2": .iPhoneXS,
        "iPhone11,4": .iPhoneXSMax,
        "iPhone11,6": .iPhoneXSMax,
        "iPhone11,8": .iPhoneXR,
        "iPhone12,1": .iPhone11,
        "iPhone12,3": .iPhone11Pro,
        "iPhone12,5": .iPhone11ProMax,
        //AppleTV
        "AppleTV5,3": .AppleTV,
        "AppleTV6,2": .AppleTV_4K
    ]

    if let model = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: modelCode!)!] {
        if model == .simulator {
            if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                if let simModel = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: simModelCode)!] {
                    return simModel
                }
            }
        }
        return model
    }
    return EnumModel.unrecognized
}
}
```

Don't forget to give custom class to label, textfield, button, textView from storyboard.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
   struct fontSizeConstant{

        static let relativeFontConstant : CGFloat = 0.015
        static let bigFontConst : CGFloat = 0.050
        static let lessBigFontConst : CGFloat = 0.040
        static let mediumFontConst : CGFloat = 0.030
    }
userName.font = userName.font?.withSize(self.view.frame.height * fontSizeConstant.mediumFontConst)

            password.font = password.font?.withSize(self.view.frame.height * fontSizeConstant.mediumFontConst)

            loginButton.titleLabel?.font = loginButton.titleLabel?.font.withSize(self.view.frame.height * fontSizeConstant.lessBigFontConst)
```

Answer (score -1):

iOS categorizes all the available devices into Regular and Compact width, height combination.

In your Xib file, Font and heights of the each item can be specified per device type meanring wR hR, wR hC, wC hR, wC hC
[image: Label attribute inspector]

Similarly, for height constraint
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately iPhone 5S and iPhone Xr, Plus fall in the same size class no help.